# Refactor and upgrade old typescript code - moleculer service - property does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, typescript, compiler-errors, moleculer

We have a 5 years old nodejs source code which must be upgraded to the latest nodejs technology, packages, typescript compiler. We found a piece of code which uses the `moleculer` nodejs package, and a code looks as:

```
broker.createService({
 name: 'file',
 actions: {
  save: {
      handler(ctx) {
        return new this.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload', ctx.meta.filename);
          const f = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
          f.on("close", () => {
            // !!! calling this.logger  !!!!
            this.logger.info(`Uploaded file stored in '${filePath}'`);
            resolve(filePath);
          });
          f.on("error", err => reject(err));

          ctx.params.pipe(f);
        });
      }
    }
 }
})
```

As per code line `this.logger.info()` the typescript compiler says:

> error TS2339: Property 'logger' does not exist on type ...

How to handle this error?

Also: we can add `actions` and `methods` to this service:

```
methods: {
  createQueueHandler(queueName, handler) { ... {
}
```

but calling this on an action

```
created() {
      this.logger.info(`RabbitMQService CREATED`);
      this.createQueueHandler(pdfConverterCompletedQueue, pdfCompleteHandler.bind(this));
    },
```

also causes compiler error:

> Error TS2339: Property 'createQueueHandler' does not exist on type

It is a different problem - how to handle this?

"moleculer": 0.14.29, typescript: 5.1.6, and tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "esnext", "dom" ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build/src",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,    
    "sourceMap" :true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types" : [ "node" ],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "**/*.integration.ts" ]
}
```

Comment: `(this as any).logger` will do the trick - but a little bit nasty for me :(

Comment: Which version of moleculer, typescript and also which tsconfig settings are you using?

Comment: Use `ctx.broker.logger.info(...message)`